# jQuery Clipboard Plugin not working on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zeroclipboard

I'm using the [jQuery Clipboard](https://github.com/valeriansaliou/jquery.clipboard) plugin.

JS:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.the_clipboard').clipboard({
        path: 'path/to/jquery.clipboard.swf',
        copy: function() {
            return jQuery(this).parent().find('.copyable').text();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <span class="copyable">TO_BE_COPIED</span>
    <button class="the_clipboard btn btn-sm" style="margin-top:-2px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span>
    </button>
</td>
```

When new `td` elements are added then the text doesn't get copied to the clipboard, when `the_clipboard` is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to call the `clipboard` plugin on the `.the_clipboard` elements is only run on page load. You will need to run it again on the `td` elements that are added dynamically.